# Which way is the best for thread synchronization?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

Which is the most robust?
And what is difference?

1.

```
[Synchronization]
public class Person : ContextBoundObject
{
    public void Print(){
        Console.WriteLine ("Start");
        Thread.Sleep (100);
        Console.WriteLine ("END");
    }
}
```

2.

```
        private readonly object obj = new object();
        public void Print(){
            lock (obj) {
                Console.WriteLine ("Start");
                Thread.Sleep (100);
                Console.WriteLine ("END");
            }
        }
```

By the way, main:

```
            Person a = new Person ();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                new Thread (a.Print).Start ();
            }
```

Can we use this two way interchangeable ?

Comment: Add the console output you expect to the question, we can only guess what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: aim for this code is to create thread-safe methods and both variants works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SynchronizationAttribute` and `ContextBoundObject` are .NET Remoting concepts; they're not intended for use in general-purpose code, and will only work on the full .NET framework (not in Windows Phone, Windows Store apps or Silverlight). Also, it forces you to make your class inherit `ContextBoundObject`, which might not be desirable.

On the other hand, `lock` will work anywhere, and doesn't force you to inherit a specific class; it is also more fine-grained, as you can apply it to just the code that needs it, rather than the entire class.

So unless your code specifically has to do with remoting, I would advice against the use of `[Synchronization]`.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly vote for method 1 over method 2.  I am taking your question as a high level real world implementation strategy type of question.

Think of the Print method as “DoMyMainObjectWorkInThisNewThread()” then the model you setup with new Thread ().Start ()  will have an object out there executing that then can interact with other threads with methods on the Person object that you have protected within your Person class.

If you lock the whole object you do not have easy interaction with your thread at a class level such as “current status” messages.

Your method “1” will guarantee you the most flexibility in the long run as you can use mutexes or objects that only provide locking and then use delegates to interact with the long running processes. (I assume Thread.Sleep is a placeholder for a long running process you do not control.)
Then you do not need the [Synchronization] class attribute and are setup for a more free threaded approach.

Also your scenario 2 would queue up the Print commands.  So a "TryLock" concept or a new method on your Person Object such as "IsPrinting()" or "CanPrint()" can be implemented.

Comment: Grats. That answer is ignorant to the source and limited scope of 1 AND against recommendet best practicess. Maybe time to learn a little more about .NET? -1.

Comment: I am doing just fine, but thank you for your input and concern, it is noted, have a nice day.